# Explicitly calling named functions inside solidity proxy contracts

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am referencing the the Gnosis-safe proxy function here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/proxies/SafeProxy.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-3.0-only
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/// @title IProxy - Helper interface to access masterCopy of the Proxy on-chain
/// @author Richard Meissner - <richard@gnosis.io>
interface IProxy {
    function masterCopy() external view returns (address);
}

/// @title GnosisSafeProxy - Generic proxy contract allows to execute all transactions applying the code of a master contract.
/// @author Stefan George - <stefan@gnosis.io>
/// @author Richard Meissner - <richard@gnosis.io>
contract GnosisSafeProxy {
    // singleton always needs to be first declared variable, to ensure that it is at the same location in the contracts to which calls are delegated.
    // To reduce deployment costs this variable is internal and needs to be retrieved via `getStorageAt`
    address internal singleton;

    /// @dev Constructor function sets address of singleton contract.
    /// @param _singleton Singleton address.
    constructor(address _singleton) {
        require(_singleton != address(0), "Invalid singleton address provided");
        singleton = _singleton;
    }

    /// @dev Fallback function forwards all transactions and returns all received return data.
    fallback() external payable {
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            let _singleton := and(sload(0), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
            // 0xa619486e == keccak("masterCopy()"). The value is right padded to 32-bytes with 0s
            if eq(calldataload(0), 0xa619486e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) {
                mstore(0, _singleton)
                return(0, 0x20)
            }
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
            let success := delegatecall(gas(), _singleton, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            if eq(success, 0) {
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
            return(0, returndatasize())
        }
    }
}
```

There are no named functions inside `GnosisSafeProxy`, and all calls to the Proxy will direct to `fallback`. In my use case, I'd like to have a few named functions inside the proxy, for example, I may want to do:

```
function namedFn(address _alice){
    /// in pseudo-code:
    /// call contract@singleton.namedFn(_alice)
}
```

1. I assume this is possible, if not an anti-pattern. But what would be the syntax for referencing `contract@singleton.namedFn`?
2. If I want `GnosisSafeProxy` to be `Initializable`, and let's assume `GnosisSafeProxy` is proxying an `GnosisSafeUpgradeable`,  so that I can do an initialization of `GnosisSafeProxy` with:

```
    function initGnosisSafeProxy(address _singleton, address _alice, address _bob ) initializer public {
         singleton = _singleton;
         contract@singleton.initialize(_alice,_bob);
    }
```

This would also be possible assuming I can reference `contract@singleton` correct? What would be the syntax here, and is there some egregious error that I'm committing here conceptually?